# Is there a better way to use a function for multiple buttons?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use a function for multiple buttons. I have a loop and for every button is clicked I want to add a specific class to the element

```js
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", openAside);
}
```

```js
function openAside() {
    document.querySelectorAll("#overlay").classList.add("active");
}
```

but for some reason i got

> Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
> at HTMLDivElement.openAside

I feel like its a basic mistake, but I'm new to javascript and I can't really figure it out.

Comment: Use `querySelector`, not `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Change `querySelectorAll` to `querySelector`. the former returns a nodelist while the latter returns a single element

Comment: @Barmar That would make the `#overlay` button always get the `active` class no matter which button you click on.

Comment: @ScottMarcus There's nothing in the question that suggests it should do something else.

Comment: @Barmar I interpret this to mean just that: *I have a loop and for every button is clicked I want to add a specific class to the element*

Comment: He didn't say "add a specific class to the button". I interpret "the element" to mean the overlay, not the button.

Answer (score 1):

[`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a node list (collection of elements) and a collection of elements doesn't have a `classList`, a single element does. Instead make the code

```
this.classList.add("active");
```

because `this` will be bound to the object that triggered the event callback in the first place, which is the element that you want the style added to.

But, better yet, instead of looping over all the buttons and attaching the same event listener to each of them, use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and just add a single event listener to the parent of all the buttons. Because events bubble, the event will reach the parent and is handled there. When it is handled, using [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) you can access the object that initially triggered the event and operate on it that way.

Here's an example:

```js
// Add the event listener to the parent
document.querySelector(".buttons").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  // Whichever button was clicked will be the: event.target
  event.target.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

```css
.active { background-color:#ff0; }
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button type="button">One</button> 
  <button type="button">Two</button> 
  <button type="button">Three</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The code in the question adds the class to a different element, not the button.